# Make Python bool print 'On' or 'Off' rather than 'True' or 'False'

Tags: python, printing, boolean

What is the best way to make a variable that works exactly like a bool but prints `On` or `Off` rather than `True` or `False`? Currently the program is printing: `Color: True`, whereas `Color: On` would make more sense.

For the record, I initially tried to make an `OnOff` class that inherits from `bool`:

```
class OnOff(bool):
    def __str__(self):
        if self: return 'On'
        else: return 'Off'
```

From the comments, I now understand that `bool` is a singleton, which is why this failed miserably:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    class OnOff(bool):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'bool' is not an acceptable base type
```

Comment: I don't think the code is relevant to the problem: I just want to make a variable that acts exactly like a bool, but prints `On` and `Off` in place of `True` or `False`.

Comment: @Josh: This is not "do my homework for me.com".  Please post the code you tried so that we can see what you're level of understanding is.

Comment: @S.Lott: This isn't homework, and as I've said, I don't have any code relevant to the problem itself. If you must see some code, take a look [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~joshbrown/snakes-game/menu/annotate/head:/menu.py).

Comment: @Josh: It helps a lot to (1) attempt the problem itself, and (2) post the code you tried.  A real lot.  We take a dim view of "write this code for me, please" questions.

Comment: @S.Lott: I post code if I have any, it's just that I'm new to OOP and in this case I didn't even have a clue how to start. I did try to create a class that inherits from bool, but it failed miserably - are you saying I should have posted that code?

Comment: @Josh: Yes.  Absolutely.

Comment: I'd deleted the code that I wrote initially, but I've added it to the question from memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`print ("Off", "On")[value]` works too (because `(False, True) == (0,1)`)

Answer (score 10):

```
def Color(object):

    def __init__(self, color_value=False):
        self.color_value = color_value

    def __str__(self):
       if self.color_value:
          return 'On'
       else:
          return 'Off'

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return self.color_value.__cmp__(other.color_value)
```

Although this could be overkill for you. :)

Comment: This is the best solution so far, but that class won't work like a normal bool at all.

Comment: If you want to make it work like a normal bool override the <code>__eq__</code> method.

Comment: Actually, the `__nonzero__` hook implements truth value testing.

Comment: Isn't it possible to inherit from `bool`?

Comment: That does not seem to be the right thing to do. Color has nothing to do with the <code>bool</code> type. Composition over inheritance for me as it gives greater control.

Comment: Color *is* bool. I just want to change the print output (something that I thought would be quite easy).

Comment: If `Color` doesn't need to be a distinct type from `bool`, then this answer is overkill.  @Josh, if I'm reading this right, you're concerned with *presentation*, not internal *representation* or *operation*.  Internally, you want it to *be* a bool, right?  If all you are concerned with is presentation, then you use a function other than `str()` to convert from `bool` to `str`.  Like, say, `['Off','On'][my_bool_value]`.

Comment: @Mike: That's not very practical for me, I've updated the first post explaining why.

Answer (score 7):

My favorite trick is to use the bool to index an array:

```
return "Color: {0}".format(['Off','On'][has_color])
```

The caveat is that the value has to be `False`, `True`, `0`, or `1`.  If you have something else, then you have to convert it to boolean first.

Comment: Wouldn't a tuple `('Off','On')[has_color]` be more efficient?

Comment: @Josh: Honestly, I have no idea. The only guaranteed difference is that a list is mutable and a tuple is not, and here that doesn't matter. IIRC, the list is crested

Answer (score 4):

```
print "On" if color else "Off"    # Python 2.x
print ("On" if color else "Off")  # Python 3.x
```

Comment: The print statement is inside a class that loops over external variables, so this isn't very practical.

Answer (score 3):

True and False are singletons. There is only one True and one False object in python. As a result attempting to inherit from them causes issues. (They just were not meant to be used in that way).

You cannot overload the logical and/or operations which will prevent you from creating a really bool-like object. It'll constantly revert back to python's bool.

So: Don't.

If you don't want your values to print as True and False, don't call print on them directly. Print is for quick and dirty output. If you want something more then it gives then you'll need to do more work. In this case, all you need is to ToOnOff function.

Answer (score 1):

I am now using this solution based off [Rahul's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687109#3687134):

```
class OnOff(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __str__(self):
       if self._value: return 'On'
       else: return 'Off'

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return self._value.__cmp__(other)
```

I changed the `__cmp__` function to enable the object to compare to bools and also changed some other minor stuff. Full credit to [Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304533).

Comment: This is the code I used in the end. Despite this, I thought [Rahul's code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687109#3687134) deserves the tick.

Comment: [Actually, I've changed my mind, I've found a way of doing this without creating a class.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687109#3691891)

Answer (score 0):

```
mybool = {True: 'On', False: 'Off'}
mybool[True] == 'On'
mybool[False] == 'Off'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with `print`...

```
class BoolHack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        from sys import stdout
        self.realout = stdout

    def write(self, text):
        if text == 'False':
            text = 'Off'
        elif text == 'True':
            text = 'On'
        self.realout.write(text)

import sys

sys.stdout = BoolHack()

print "Hello world" # ==> Hello world
print 1             # ==> 1
print True, 10      # ==> On 10
print False         # ==> Off
print "True hack"   # ==> True hack
```

WARNING: Do not use in real production code! This is only for making your set of answers complete.

`print` calls str() on objects to print, and only then puts the string to stdout... so you cant check type of object. But it is quite rare to just print 'False' or 'True' as a single string, so in your very very specific case it might work.

Comment: why would you give people such terrible ideas!

Comment: @Winston Ewert: even the crudest hack is sometimes useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self,C):
    if C==True:
        self.col='On'
    else:
        self.col='Off'

    def __cmp__(self,other):
        return self.col
```

Answer (score 0):

Pity you can't do `True.__str__=lambda:"On"`

Unfortunately it complains it is read-only.  Anyway, that would be a VERY hackish way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this curious one:

```
a = True
b = False
print a and 'On' or 'Off'
print b and 'On' or 'Off'
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the advice of the public, I've changed my mind and found a better way to solve my problem than by creating a class: Convert the menu items to strings *outside* the class. Allowing me to use [the solution proposed by THC4k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687109#3687180).

[Unidiff](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~joshbrown/snakes-game/menu/revision/4/menu.py):

```
         menu.items=((
             ('Play Game', True),
             '  ',
             'Speed: ', (speed, True),
             '  ',
             'Screen: ', (screen_width, True), 'x', (screen_height, True),
             '  ',
-            'Color: ', (color, True),
+            'Color: ', (("Off", "On")[color], True),
             '  ',
             ('Exit', True)
         ))
```

*(I did the same for the other variables, I'm just trying to be succinct with the diff)*